# How can I stream Pandora to my Xbox 360?

Tags: streaming, xbox360, pandora

How can I get pandora to stream to my xbox 360? My initial thoughts would indicate that I would need a software-emulated sound card, and then I would need a program to attach to that soundcard and perform the actual streaming.

Has anyone done this before? If so, do you have instructions on how to do so?

Comment: wait. "emulated sound card"? what?  where are you trying to "stream" from?  what systems in your house are at issue here besides the xbox?

Comment: If you have a software sound device, you can point audio player XYZ at the sound device, then take that input and stream it via some utility. I'm wondering if there's a program that does this automatically, or if not, what programs could accomplish the above given tasks.

Comment: Jamcast does just what I need, I just found out, but I'm looking for a free solution.

Comment: so... you're trying to take Pandora's stream to your desktop PC and then stream it out again to the xbox?

Comment: I just need to stream to the xbox 360, but it seems like the two-legged solution should be easier to find/implement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Jamcast](http://www.sdstechnologies.com/) is the only solution I've found, and it's not free.

Answer (score 0):

You can stream now using the browser that was recently added:
http://rrfreeman.blogspot.com/2012/12/pandora-on-xbox-360.html

Comment: Could you elaborate more instead of giving out link to your blog?